# Ehcache3 Impact of persistence on performance, Disk Tier to be used anyways

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, ehcache, ehcache-3

Version: Ehcache 3.8

```
<ehcache:cache alias="10">
        <ehcache:key-type>java.lang.String</ehcache:key-type>
        <ehcache:value-type>byte[]</ehcache:value-type>
        <ehcache:expiry>
            <ehcache:ttl unit="seconds">86400</ehcache:ttl>
        </ehcache:expiry>
        <ehcache:resources>
            <ehcache:heap unit="MB">1</ehcache:heap>
            <ehcache:offheap unit="MB">400</ehcache:offheap>
            <ehcache:disk unit="GB" persistent="true">5</ehcache:disk>
        </ehcache:resources>
    </ehcache:cache>
```

Is there any impact on performance if persistent is kept as true. Disk tier is to be used. I wanted to know is persistent flag is just for restartability or does it have performance impact too.